# Как сделать авторизацию на тестовом сервере AWS?

Tags: сервер, авторизация, аутентификация, amazon, amazon-web-services

Сервер на котором тестируется продукт перед деплоем в продакшн. Его нужно скрыть от ненужных глаз, как сделать аутентификацию на амазоне ? Может это в настройках где-то можно включить